# Issues with the Shotgun Gem - RuntimeError

Tags: ruby, runtime-error, shotgun

I'm getting this error when I try and run a simple ruby app using `shotgun`:

```
    Jons-MacBook-Pro:sin jonread$ shotgun simple.rb
    == Shotgun/Thin on http://127.0.0.1:9393/
    >> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
    >> Maximum connections set to 1024
    >> Listening on 127.0.0.1:9393, CTRL+C to stop
    /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_server'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:16:in `connect'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:55:in `block in start'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/shotgun-        0.9/bin/shotgun:156:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/shotgun:23:in `load'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/shotgun:23:in `<main>'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
        from /Users/jonread/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas on why this is happening or a quick way to fix it?

Comment: Is it because you already have an instance of the server running? Look in the error message, it reads: "port is in use or requires root privileges".

Comment: Thanks Josh.  How would I check that?

Comment: On Mac you can search for processes using that port with `lsof -i tcp:9393` where `9393` is the port you are looking for. Once you have found that port, you can kill the runaway process and try re-running your program.

Answer (score 5):

Josh Voigt's answer in the comments worked for me.

```
macbook:cpaphires johnnygoodman$ lsof -i tcp:3000
COMMAND   PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    24976 johnnygoodman    8u  IPv4 0xffffff8020b71fa0      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
macbook:cpaphires johnnygoodman$ kill -9 24976
macbook:cpaphires johnnygoodman$ lsof -i tcp:3000
macbook:cpaphires johnnygoodman$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Which fixed this error:

> > Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
> >     Exiting
> >     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in`start_server'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:16:in `connect'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:55:in`block in start'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in`run_machine'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in`start'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in`run'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in`start'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`tap'
> >         from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
> >         from script/rails:6:in`require'
> >         from script/rails:6:in `'